# How to save EntityObject

Tags: entity-framework-4

Lets say i have a lot of entity classes.
I have a db context.

I have a code

```
Person p=new Person();
p.Name="test";
```

Note, that there is no lines with context.

How must I save this object using context, if context only knows that it is `EntityObject`?

UPDATE:

```
if (obj.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
                context.AddObject(obj.EntityKey.EntitySetName, obj);
```

but obj.EntityKey is null, so it does not work

UPDATE2:

I have a code:

```
public static void EntitySave(EntityObject obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(obj.GetType().Name, obj.GetType().Name + " не должен быть пустым");
            var context = GetSqlConnection();

            if (obj.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
                context.AddObject(obj.EntityKey.EntitySetName, obj);//there is an exception

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

and one another:

```
 public static void SaveNewPerson()
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            EntitySave(p);//there is an exception
        }
```

So how `EntitySave` should save the object correctly? Or may be i need a helper functions to create each entities classes?

Comment: Clarify your question. Context must know the entity type.

Comment: Person is derived from EntityObject (as usual). Is this possible if context doesnot know the type of object?

Comment: "//there is an exception" - well, what is it?? you can't expect us to help if you don't provide enough information.

Comment: cause of obj.EntityKey is null then it is  NullException

Comment: the problem is not in Exception, the problem is in that I cannot just make new Person() and then attach new object as EntityObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it by passing EntityObject alone, because a newly created EntityObject has no info on the entity set. You can create a helper function or a helper dictionary, something like

```
private static Dictionary<Type, string> _entitySets = new Dictionary<Type, string>
{
    { typeof(Person), "Persons"},         
    { typeof(Address), "Addresses"}
}

...

public static void EntitySave(EntityObject obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("не должен быть пустым");

    var context = GetSqlConnection();
    if (obj.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
        context.AddObject(EntitySets[obj.GetType()], obj);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Just check if the set name is "Persons" or "PersonsSet"

Answer (score 1):

It is still not clear what you mean by *"context doesn't know the type of object"*. The context must know the type of object otherwise it doesn't know how to map and persist the object. The type of the object is described in EDMX.

If you just want to add object to the context you must use either:

```
// You must say the name of EntitySet where you want to add the object
context.AddObject("PersonsSet", person);
```

or:

```
// You must call the AddObject method on correct object set
context.CreateObjectSet<Person>().AddObject(person);
```

Default code generation also offers specific method like `AddPerson` or something like that.